# Group by unique pairs with no multiplicity

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a table AreaLocation with AreaID as the PKey and Location whereby there are many locations for each AreaID. Correspondingly there is another table Books with:

```
BookingID | DriverID | BLocation | Miles | Fare
```

I'm trying to get the average efficiency of each driver by area, i.e. I'd looking for a view with

```
| DriverID | AreaID | AVERAGE(Fare/Miles) |
```

where I'd like to group by distinct DriverID/AreaID however I'm not sure whether the following will work:

```
CREATE VIEW EFFICIENCY AS
 SELECT AreaID, Bookings.DriverID, AVERAGE(Bookings.Fare/Bookings.Miles) 
 FROM AreaLocations
 RIGHT JOIN Bookings ON
 ( AreaLocations.Location = Bookings.Location )
 GROUP BY DISTINCT (AreaID, Bookings.DriverID)
```

as I don't think distinct works on pairs.

Comment: ??? GROUP BY itself produces distinct grouping expression value. `GROUP BY AreaLocations.AreaID, Bookings.DriverID`

Comment: *`AVERAGE(Bookings.Fare/Bookings.Miles)`* - a) no function AVERAGE b) looks illogical c) may cause 'divide by zero' error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that this is using the syntax provided for in class (we assume there's a function called AVERAGE)

Comment: @Akina Oh so that extends to pairs, and it won't include multiplicities I assume? How does it look illogical? And there won't be a divide by 0 error as we assume the tables are full with non-zero entries.

Comment: Provide your tables as CREATE TABLE scripts. Add some sample data as INSERT INTO scripts. Then show desired output for this data.

Comment: *How does it look illogical?* I'd prefer `SUM(Fare)/SUM(Miles)` more believable.

Comment: @Akina I mean the desired output is pretty straightforward, it's just the grouping by unique pairs part that has me stumped. But if you said that works as I have it then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

With full_Group_on you can use for example this, if a "_" is not present  your columns

```
CREATE VIEW EFFICIENCY AS
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(area_driver, '_', 1) as AreaID,SUBSTRING_INDEX(area_driver, '_', -1) AS DriverID, AvgPrice
 FROM (SELECT CONCAT(AreaID,"_",Bookings.DriverID) area_driver, AVERAGE(Bookings.Fare/Bookings.Miles) AvgPrice
 FROM AreaLocations
 RIGHT JOIN Bookings ON
 ( AreaLocations.Location = Bookings.Location )
 GROUP BY  CONCAT(AreaID,"_",Bookings.DriverID)) f1
```

Comment: I know this works but I feel like there is a simpler solution rather than using substrings and instead inner/outer joins.

Comment: i thought about it but a full group on will fail with most others.