# SQL to Determine which Row Combinations have the Most Occurrences

Tags: sql-server

I have a table InvoiceData

| VendorNum | InvNum | AU | Acct | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Invoice 1 | 9010 | 40006 | 459.00 |
| 12345 | Invoice 2 | 9010 | 40006 | 425.50 |
| 12345 | Invoice 2 | 9010 | 40007 | 425.50 |
| 12345 | Invoice 3 | 9010 | 40006 | 33 |
| 12345 | Invoice 3 | 9010 | 40007 | 33 |
| 12345 | Invoice 3 | 9010 | 40008 | 33 |
| 12345 | Invoice 4 | 9010 | 40006 | 683.00 |
| 12345 | Invoice 5 | 9010 | 40006 | 314.00 |
| 12345 | Invoice 6 | 9010 | 40006 | 85.25 |
| 12345 | Invoice 6 | 9010 | 40007 | 85.25 |
| 12345 | Invoice 7 | 9010 | 40006 | 99.00 |
| 12345 | Invoice 7 | 9010 | 40007 | 99.00 |
| 12345 | Invoice 8 | 9010 | 40006 | 4278 |
| 12345 | Invoice 8 | 9010 | 40007 | 4278 |

I am looking to find the Combination of AU,ACCT That occurs most for all InvNum for a VendorNum

I am having trouble thinking through the logic for structuring the SQL

Select TOP 1 AU,Acct,Count(*) from InvoiceData group by AU,ACCT Only returns the total of all occurrences aggregated across all invoices.

id like to know which row combination occurs Most

| AU | ACCT |
| --- | --- |
| 9010 | 40006 |
| 9010 | 40007 |
| ---- | ---- |
| Total: | 4 |

Comment: HI @ChadTucker - the example data seems to ignore vendornum?? Also can't you just add another group by and sum to get maximums?

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the columns to get the most ocuurances

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     ([VendorNum] int, [InvNum] varchar(9), [AU] int, [Acct] int, [Amt] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     ([VendorNum], [InvNum], [AU], [Acct], [Amt])
> VALUES
>     (12345, 'Invoice 1', 9010, 40006, 459.00),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 2', 9010, 40006, 425.50),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 2', 9010, 40007, 425.50),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 3', 9010, 40006, 33),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 3', 9010, 40007, 33),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 3', 9010, 40008, 33),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 4', 9010, 40006, 683.00),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 5', 9010, 40006, 314.00),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 6', 9010, 40006, 85.25),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 6', 9010, 40007, 85.25),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 7', 9010, 40006, 99.00),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 7', 9010, 40007, 99.00),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 8', 9010, 40006, 4278),
>     (12345, 'Invoice 8', 9010, 40007, 4278)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TOP 1 [AU], [Acct] , COUNT(*) countr FROM Table1 GROUP BY [AU], [Acct] ORDER BY countr DESC
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   AU |  Acct | countr
> ---: | ----: | -----:
> 9010 | 40006 |      8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=609c8cde1e3c3a196cecc66ef2614e26)*

Comment: This is the top single occurrence - i am looking for the top combination of occurrences

Comment: i can't follow what you are searching

Comment: For instance on these 8 invoices the combination 9010|40006 9010|40007 occurs 4 times. I would like a query to tell me that this combination of rows across all invoices occurs the most

Comment: that is what the query makes. that is why i can't follow you

Comment: The query you provided gives me all occurences of 9010|40006....

9010|40006 occurs on Invoice1, Invoice 4, Invoice 5 - so this should return a count of 3

9010|40006 + 9010|40007 Occurs on Invoice 2, Invoice6, Invoice7, Invoice8 This should return a count of 4

9010|40006 + 9010|40007 + 9010|40008 occurs on Invoice 3 this should return a count of 1

Comment: i answereda  simikar question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289812/190821 this will be something similar only quite uglier as you need onyl to combone the columns but also com,bone them all for a invoice id. i will delete this answer later